# CSS determining active media query

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

In Javascript is there a direct way (not involving parsing the css code) to determine which media query is active?

For instance I have two queries:

```
 @media screen and (max-width:800px)

 @media screen and (min-width:801px)
```

without parsing and looking at the clientWidth, how can I tell which one of these has evaluated to true.

Comment: Yes I can do that, but that presumes I have an element to compute from. I am trying to fill in the data based upon the media query,  i have no elements in place yet and it seems very "hacky" to put in some element with some bogus data to make this determination.

Comment: You could set the background/border of one of the containers/DIVs to appear bright red when one of the widths (as a temporary measure) is triggered?

Answer (score 19):

*Though this is an old question it ranks highly when googling for this problem.*

[Window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) is official and is supported by [all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=matchmedia) (IE10+) and will allow you to query if a certain media query currently matches.

From the original question:

```
if (window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width:800px)').matches) {
    // it matches
} else {
    // does not match
}
```

You can also listen for when the query match result changes by attaching an event listener to the [MediaQueryList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) that `window.matchMedia` returns:

```
var mql = window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width:800px)');
mql.addEventListener(
    function(mq) {
        if (mq.matches) {
            // it matches
        } else {
            // does not match
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: "*Though this is an old question*" Good summaries / updates are always welcome! Thanks!

Comment: `addEventListener` requires two arguments, so I believe maybe theres a typo or just the evolving of language, so use `addListener` instead

Answer (score 0):

Paul Irish's MatchMedia may do the trick:
https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js

Would that suit what you are trying to do?

Comment: It will work..., however I was looking for a more elegant approach :-(

Answer (score 0):

To see how different media queries react on resize or orientation change, try the demo on this page:

http://www.jensbits.com/2011/04/20/media-query-playground-rotate-resize-rinse-repeat/

You can adjust the media query attributes to get a feel for how they affect a page.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and i hope this helps, am actually adding a class to a selector and i am working with this tool: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/06/using-window-matchmedia-to-do-media-queries-in-javascript/

in fact, they have a clear example of what is turn on within the resized window here
http://robnyman.github.io/matchmedia/

in my case am just doing specific task when am on a specific size that you can get using the function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how would you know which media-query is active, but...

...can't you just check the screen width with javascript?

```
if ( window.innerWidth >= 801 ) {
    // @media screen and (min-width:801px)
} else {
    // @media screen and (max-width:800px
}
```

or, what am i missing here?

Comment: oh, just saw _without parsing and looking at the clientWidth,_, sorry